# c++ template input validation

Tags: c++, validation, templates, input

I am using the following for easily extracting input and validating the correct type. However, the end of file EOF is not being fired.

```
template< typename T >
std::istream& read(std::istream &istr, T &val)
{
    std::string s;
    std::getline(istr, s);

    if (istr.good())
    {
        s.erase(s.find_last_not_of(" \n") + 1);

        std::stringstream iss(s);

        iss >> val;

        if (! iss.good())
            istr.setstate(std::ios::failbit);

        char c;
        if (iss.get(c))
            istr.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
    }

    return istr;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int input = 0;

    std::cout << "Please enter an integer>" << std::flush;

    for (;;)
    {
        if (read(std::cin, input))
            break;

        std::cin.clear();
        std::cout << "Please, enter only an INTEGER>" << std::flush;
    }

    std::cout << "Press <enter> to quit>";
    std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits< std::streamsize >::max(), '\n');
    return 0;
}
```

"111" entered does not validate as an integer when it should.

Comment: This also fails on getting a single char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iss >> val` reads all the characters and "touches" the end of stream, so it sets off EOF every time.

```
template< typename T >
std::istream& read(std::istream &istr, T &val)
{
    std::string s;
    std::getline(istr, s);

    if (istr.good()) {
        std::istringstream iss(s); //leave the '\n'

        if (! (iss >> val))
            istr.setstate(std::ios::failbit);

        //if it gets another character that isn't a newline
        char a=0;
        if (iss.get(a) && a!='\n') 
            istr.setstate(std::ios::failbit);
    }

    return istr;
}
```

Comment: If I change the input type to an int, and enter " 1" (notice the space) it accepts it, which it should not do.

Comment: @rem45acp : If you want whitespace to be _that_ significant, then standard I/O streams are not the right tool for the job. Give [Boost.Spirit](http://www.boost.org/libs/spirit/)'s `auto_` parser a shot.

Comment: All formatted input skips whitespace.  If you don't want to allow spaces, you'll have to write your own routine using unformatted input.

Comment: You're right, space is not significant there. However, putting iss.get(a) now breaks  the function for an integer. See my edit on my original post.

Comment: @rem45acp: I did tests myself, and the problem wasn't remotely what I thought it was.  Corrected.